# How to configure multiple exchanges in laravel-queue-rabbitmq?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, rabbitmq, laravel-queue

I have found [famous library](https://github.com/vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq) for using RabbitMQ in Laravel.

In configuration `config/queue.php` 
I can specify only one exchange and queue name.
Does it 
support multiple exchanges?

Comment: I mean register some exchange in server side using Laravel, cause now config provides only one exchange name

Comment: In RabbitMQ you always post messages on an exchange and consume messages from a queue. Still not clear what you mean. I think Laravel refers to exchanges (which are solely a RabbitMQ concept) as Queues in general (SQS, Redis etc.). Did you have a look at this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#connections-vs-queues ?

Comment: Okay, what does mean exchange configuration in setting of this library?

Comment: I know I ask why in configuration of this drive there is only one exchange?

Comment: `'options' => [
    
            'exchange' => [
    
                'name' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_NAME'),....`

Comment: Sure, that is question, why this driver supports only one exchange and queue?

Comment: Maybe you can recommend another more flexible library for Laravel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For future people who will search the answer for this  question.
There is one(bad) way to add multiple exchanges. You have to duplicate rabbitmq connection with new exchange and when you will want to publish the message to new exchange, you will just change connection.

This is a very ugly way, but i didn't another one. Laravel queue doesn't provide a method to change the exchange, but there is the method `onConnection` what you help you.

Here is a simple example

```
        'conn_one' => [

        'driver' => 'rabbitmq',
        'queue' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE', 'default'),
        'connection' => PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPLazyConnection::class,

        'hosts' => [
            [
                'host' => env('RABBITMQ_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                'port' => env('RABBITMQ_PORT', 5672),
                'user' => env('RABBITMQ_USER', 'guest'),
                'password' => env('RABBITMQ_PASSWORD', 'guest'),
                'vhost' => env('RABBITMQ_VHOST', '/'),
            ],
        ],

        'options' => [
            'ssl_options' => [
                'cafile' => env('RABBITMQ_SSL_CAFILE', null),
                'local_cert' => env('RABBITMQ_SSL_LOCALCERT', null),
                'local_key' => env('RABBITMQ_SSL_LOCALKEY', null),
                'verify_peer' => env('RABBITMQ_SSL_VERIFY_PEER', true),
                'passphrase' => env('RABBITMQ_SSL_PASSPHRASE', null),
            ],
            'queue' => [
                'job' => VladimirYuldashev\LaravelQueueRabbitMQ\Queue\Jobs\RabbitMQJob::class,
                'exchange' => 'exchange_two',
                'exchange_type' => 'fanout',
            ],
        ],

     ],

    'conn_two' => [
        'driver' => 'rabbitmq',
        'queue' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE', 'default'),
        'connection' => PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPLazyConnection::class,

        'hosts' => [
            [
                'host' => env('RABBITMQ_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                'port' => env('RABBITMQ_PORT', 5672),
                'user' => env('RABBITMQ_USER', 'guest'),
                'password' => env('RABBITMQ_PASSWORD', 'guest'),
                'vhost' => env('RABBITMQ_VHOST', '/'),
            ],
        ],

        'options' => [
            'ssl_options' => [
                'cafile' => env('RABBITMQ_SSL_CAFILE', null),
                'local_cert' => env('RABBITMQ_SSL_LOCALCERT', null),
                'local_key' => env('RABBITMQ_SSL_LOCALKEY', null),
                'verify_peer' => env('RABBITMQ_SSL_VERIFY_PEER', true),
                'passphrase' => env('RABBITMQ_SSL_PASSPHRASE', null),
            ],
            'queue' => [
                'job' => VladimirYuldashev\LaravelQueueRabbitMQ\Queue\Jobs\RabbitMQJob::class,
                'exchange' => 'exchange_two',
                'exchange_type' => 'fanout',
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

**Use**

```
ExampleJob::dispach($data)->onConnection('conn_one');
ExampleJob::dispach($data)->onConnection('conn_two');
```

Answer (score 0):

Or another ugly way could be to set config like this

```
Config::set('queue.connections.rabbitmq.options.queue.exchange', 'exchange_two');
```

before dispatching the job to the new exchange. In this way you dont have to create a duplicate connection just setting new exchange name before dispatching the job to the new exchange.